# Ruby Script Runner for Ubuntu Gedit

Tags: ruby, bash, gedit

I have this Java script runner installed in my gedit external tools:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR
if javac $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME;
then
java ${GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME%\.java}
else
echo "Failed to compile"
fi
```

I tried modifying to it to something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR
ruby ${GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME%\.rb}
```

but it doesn't work. I may have missed something, I don't know what because I don't do bash scripting. Hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME` includes the file extension.

So just do:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_DIR
ruby $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script is executable

```
chmod +x my_script.sh
```

Comment: sorry, but I don't get it...make executable the script I am applying the given code on or the bash script itself? I did not have to do any chmods with my java files,so I think that should be the same case with my ruby files. And the code given was run with gedit's External Tools, in which you are given gedit's code panel to write the script on with no actual file.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood something from your answer :(

Comment: That's okay. I meant the bash script, but if it was created through a GUI in gedit then I'd assume gedit handles that for you, but I'm not sure.

Comment: yep, it's from the GUI. I should have mentioned "gedit's code panel GUI for External Tools"